# How to generate magento 2 sitemap using shell script?

Tags: magento, magento2

Currently im generating sitemap using magento cron.

I would like to trigger sitemap generation using shell script to achieve some desired result.

Could you please let me know how to achieve this?

Regards
Palani

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Just to clarify - asking for a script doesn't mean this is about programming. If you posted a script and had a question about the code you posted then that would be about programming. This question is about getting a script coded for you. It's a outsourcing request.